# SQL - Add total from columns of two seperate tables

Tags: sql

Complete novice here, trying to find out the total number of students from both the `part-time` students and `full-tim`e students and display the total in a named column.

```
partTimeStudents**(bannerID, moduleCode, modStartDate, rvisitorID)

fullTimeStudents**(bannerID, courseCode, crsStartDate, rvisitorID)
```

Thank you in advance for any help given :)

Comment: provide with table structure or something

Comment: Again problem with database design why you have two separate tables for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  (select count(*) from partTimeStudents)+
  (select count(*) from fullTimeStudents) as Total
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree what others have said about the database design, but here's one example of a query that would fulfill your requirement.

```
SELECT SUM(students_count)
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS students_count 
   FROM partTimeStudents 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS students_count 
   FROM fullTimeStudents
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not take 2 tables just to distinguish it by full/part time student. You can simply take a flag in table like:

```
students(bannerID, Code, modStartDate, rvisitorID, timeFlag)
```

In timeFlag you can manage whether the student is full time or part time.

Now to get count of all students[full time + part time]:

```
select count(*) from students;
```

And to have counts for fullTime students or partime students:

```
select count(*) from students where tiemFlag=1; //--- assuming 1 is for fulltime
select count(*) from students where tiemFlag=0; //--- assuming 0 is for parttime
```

Comment: If `moduleCode` and `courseCode` reference different tables, then `student (bannerID, moduleCode, courseCode, startDate, rvisitorID)` might be a better schema. It would also have a constraint that enforces only one of the code columns to have value, which could serve as the way of distinguishing between a full-time student and a part-time one.

Comment: @Andriy: yes this is also a good option. At least better than the two table overhead.